# Swift 3 osx - Popup every time I use SecIdentitySetPreferred

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, identity, keychain

I am editing a lot of identity preferences in a swift 3 app. For every single domain, there is an annoying popup: "[app name] wants to access key "[domain]" in your keychain. Do you want to allow access to this item?".

How do I get rid of this popup / automatically give my app the right access any keys in my keychain?

Edit: my question is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144668/repeated-popup-xcode-wants-to-access-key-com-apple-dt-xcodedevicemonitor-in-y) because I need a programmatic solution. How do I change that setting programmatically with either Swift or AppleScript? Thanks.

Comment: Not quite, see edit.

Comment: You are right, I retracted my flag.